# How to write a corporate character that likes to toy around with his colleagues?

Tags: characters

I want to write a male, corporate working, character who is always cheerful and smiling, no matter whatever the situation he is in. As a result, reading his thoughts or motives is almost impossible. He is also good looking and smart. And he almost always agrees with everybody and just goes with the flow. Never seems to disagree with anyone or have an opinion.

And, almost all people who encounter him really just hate him and find him annoying. They hate his guts and his overwhelming persona. Most people who meet him know there is something off about him but they don't know what that is and no matter how much they try to uncover it always ends up backfiring or does more damage to them.

And they are right to be worried about him. See, while this guy is very good at his job he really as a very nasty side to him. He basically want to toy around or dick around with all of his colleagues or peers. He wants to mess around with  all of them and not really cares what happens to them or himself either. He wants people to be annoyed by him. He wants them to loathe. It makes his life more interesting and gives him some purpose to his life. Watching other people detest him excites him.

Any, suggestion how write such a character ? Make him convincing and Interesting ?

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to Writing SE! You mentioned that your character "goes with the flow" - do you mean that he's only ostensibly goes with the flow, while always pursuing a hidden agenda?

Answer (score 4):

## Misery Loves Company.

I think you'd have to make him, at least apparently, very observant and intelligent.

One way to make him hated and cheerful at the same time is to have him tell jokes about his co-workers, that hurt. To do that, he needs to be able to read their emotions, tell when they are hurting, and be able to figure out why.

You could make him a good hacker and spy, something he has hidden from his co-workers. He wears earphones a lot, like listening to music: But what he is listening to is private conversations of his fellow employees on their cell phones, or office phones. The equipment to do that kind of intercept and relay does cost $1000s, but he considers it part of his entertainment system.

He knows when people are having trouble at home, with money, with medical issues, with their spouse, with their kid's drug addiction, and he is clever enough to make jokes about this stuff that denigrate people that get into too much debt, or have erectile dysfunction or can't control their own kids or are obese and can't lose weight, but he does it in a way that prevents them from knowing they are being overheard.

Perhaps he goes further, and by occasional viewing of somebody typing a password, he is able to get enough clues about the password (number of letters, approximately where on the keyboard they are) that some available dark web password breakers give him access to the personal emails of his co-workers. So he can read those, too.

Perhaps he goes even further than that; hiring experts to put up hidden spy cams inside of people's homes. Contrary to what TV tells you, it is not difficult at all for experts to both encrypt and hide the final destination of such videos. Perhaps he wants to catch some nude pictures of his coworkers, or other bedroom activities. Material he can use anonymously, perhaps, or just know what might embarrass somebody. One of his dreams is to catch somebody cheating on their spouse or boyfriend or girlfriend. Heck, he may even hire a high end prostitute (one that doesn't **look** like a prostitute) to seduce a coworker's boyfriend, and then out him to his coworker with pictures to prove it, and ruin her relationship. All in fun.

The truth is he is miserable, he resents happiness, and enjoys punishing happiness or ruining it. That is his hobby. And like many people, he doesn't mind spending many thousands of dollars on this hobby, just for the fun it will bring him. It isn't about the money, it is just about making other people as miserable and lonely and empty as he is.

Comment: Spot on - for one version of the story, that is. Maybe one way he could use his 'secret information' is to always make the joke about someone that is not the victim of the joke. For instance, if he's making a joke about being overweight he knows that someone overweight overhears it. Same for the erectile dysfunction and so on - He's clerver enough to not make fun of something directly to the victim. The victim could even be next in line by the water-dispenser.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot tell you how to write as such creation is an intensely personal and unique process.

How might I? I would ask myself what would irk me about such a person if I encountered them. What would it take to make me detest a seemingly harmless and ever cheerful soul. People are never just one note, they may seem such on occasion but we know it is a mask worn for a purpose.

Why must he be loathed? He needs to know this absolutely and he can be wrong.

You must know who he is behind that mask of agreement, what his opinions are and how he intends to wrong the rest.

What purpose does he have behind the mask?

- Is he the mysterious owner of the company choosing to go slumming with the employees before selling the company and moving the jobs to China?
- Is he someone for whom intimacy of any sort creates pain?
- Is he from another dimension or world?

To render a character interesting and credible you must find him so yourself and believe in him, create him as a fully formed being in your imagination and know his thoughts, actions, virtues and vices - then introduce the reader to your unusual friend.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need at least two, more would be better, POVs to portray this concept effectively, the last of these should be Mr Detestable himself. Have several people dislike the man from their own point of view, they don't agree on why they don't like him, there's no unifying lodestone for their aggravation but they all hate him. Then have *his* point of view when interacting with someone new to the narrative and the joy he feels when he notices their aggravation with him.